# How to access sub elements of a custom FrameLayout in a library project?

Tags: android, user-interface, subclass, android-framelayout, lib

I am extending a "MapView" that itself extends FrameLayout. But I can't access the ui elements I added: *level_layout* and *level_scroll. I have no trouble adding the code directly to my MainActivity, but I can't get it to work in a library.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.company.com.library.mapbox.MyMapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mapView">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/level_scroll"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/level_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
</android.company.com.library.mapbox.MyMapView>
```

In *MyMapView.java* I am getting a value from:

```
int level = R.id.level_layout;
```

But *linear* is null when trying to get the *LinearLayout*

```
LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.level_layout);
```

---

I tried Adding

```
@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();
}
```

(I try to access my ui elements after this is called)

Calling the following in different places (e.g. constructors)

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService
        (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nameOfTheXmlFile, null);
```

I don't have multiple layout files with the same name.

I can't use *setContentView(...)* since this is a View and not an Activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Official documentation to `MapView` [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView) explicitly says

> Note: You are advised not to add children to this view.

This means that `MapView` custom inner views are supported only partially, or not supported at all. I would not recommend you to use something that is badly supported since it may produce weird bugs as the one you have. Especially in `MapView` with its complicated touch listener and extensive inner UI - you can easily break something(for example zoom or camera swiping with your `ScrollView`)

Frankly I'm not sure why are you doing this - you can easily place all the views you need in ordinary `FrameLayout` and everything will work fine(except maybe `ScrollView` swipe gesture processor may disrupt `MapView` gestures)

So it would be wiser do to it like this

```
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.company.com.library.mapbox.MyMapView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/mapView"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/wrapper_layout"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp">

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/level_scroll"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/level_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                </LinearLayout>

            </ScrollView>

        </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

This way you will be able to leverage all the possibilities of `MapView` and `FrameLayout` separately. Don't forget to handle lifecycle changes for the `MapView` in your fragment/activity as it is told [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView).

You may also notice that I wrapped `ScrollView` with `FrameLayout` and gave this wrapper layout wight and height, while `ScrollView` has `match_parent`. I've done that because `ScrollView` with defined height and width can be a real pain in the arse and is quite bug prone, thus wrapping it in some other layout is recommended workaround for such purposes.

While it is not the exact solution to your problem, I hope this answer will help you somehow.